# Need AppleScript to get date from website

Tags: applescript

I am in need of some AppleScript code that will go to a website (https://www.time.gov/) and return the date.  I have virtually no experience writing AppleScript code, and have had a very tough time figuring out how to do it.

A little context: the AppleScript code will be used inside an Excel workbook, inside VBA code.  The AppleScript code is assigned to a String variable and then executed.  Here’s a simple example of how that works.

```
Function FileExistsOnMac(Filestr As String) As Boolean

Dim ScriptToCheckFile As String

ScriptToCheckFile = "tell application " & Chr(34) & "System Events" & Chr(34) & _
" to return (exists disk item " & Chr(34) & Filestr & Chr(34) & ") and class of disk item " & _
    Chr(34) & Filestr & Chr(34) & " = file "

FileExistsOnMac = MacScript(ScriptToCheckFile)

End Function
```

In my case, I would have the Function be of type String (or perhaps Date) and it would return the date that the AppleScript code returned from the website.  If anyone could show me what the AppleScript code needs to be, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically need it from that website, instead of getting the date using a more conventional means, such as `get the date string of the current date` or `get the current date as string` (the latter includes the time).

Comment: I was going to get it from that website in case the user's computer clock is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scraping (i.e. by reading from the text or source code of a website) is not an ideal method to obtain date and time information, and the website you picked is particularly bad because it displays the live time through JavaScript that continuously writes and updates the contents of the page, so the actual source code for the page doesn't actually contain any readable date or time information.

The more conventional method of retrieving a time from the internet is to do from a timeserver.  *`time.gov`* have one at `nist.time.gov`, and you can request the date and time using the following bash shell command:

```
cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13
```

which returns something like this:

```
58641 19-06-07 06:19:14 50 0 0 800.5 UTC(NIST) *
```

The second and third fields are the ones you want, representing date and time, respectively.  We can clean that up a little bit with the use of `awk`:

```
cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13 | awk 'length($0)>0 {print 20$2,$3}'
```

which returns:

```
2019-06-07 06:19:14
```

Since you specifically requested an AppleScript to do this, this will return to you the date and time as above:

```
do shell script "cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13 | awk 'length($0)>0 {print 20$2,$3}'"
```

and this will return to you just the date:

```
do shell script "cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13 | awk 'length($0)>0 {print 20$2}'"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!!

Comment: Good answer. Just want to add that there are other ways to call shell scripts from Excel without using appleScript